# How to add an object to DataContext

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a Window with the DataContext set to ClientContact object.

```
Private Sub ContactWindow_Loaded(...
    Me.DataContext = myData
    ...
```

I have a textbox that references a subclass of the ClientContact object.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SpouseData.FirstName, Mode = TwoWay}" />
```

Here is the ClientContact object.

```
Public Class Data
    Public Property SpouseData() As Data
        ...
```

Initially SpouseData is nothing. When they get married, I want to add a SpouseData object. I discovered that if I set the Binding Context to nothing, I can set again and it works fine. If I don't set it to nothing first the data doesn't show.

```
Private Sub AddSpouse
    Me.myData.SpouseData = SpData
    Me.DataContext = Nothing
    Me.DataContext = myData
End Sub
```

Here's my attempt to notify changes. Tried it both ways. Didn't work.

```
Private Sub AddSpouse2
    Me.myClientData.SpouseData = SpData
    Me.myClientData.NotifySpouseVisible2()
End Sub
Private Sub AddSpouse4
    Me.myClientData.SpouseData = SpData
    Me.myClientData.SpouseData.NotifySpouseVisible2()
End Sub

Public Sub NotifySpouseVisible2()
    NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName")
    NotifyPropertyChanged("LastName")
    NotifyPropertyChanged("SSN")
    NotifyPropertyChanged("DOB")
    NotifyPropertyChanged("Age")
    NotifyPropertyChanged("CalcedAge")
End Sub
```

But it seems I shouldn't have to set the DataContext to nothing. Something like this (of course doesn't work).

```
Me.myClientData.SpouseData = SpData
Me.DataContext.addBinding(New Binding("SpouseData"))
```

So how do I add a binding to the SpouseData without setting the whole DataContext to nothing?

Comment: Are you not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @Will Yes I am/was but it wasn't working. I'll edit.

Comment: What you did in lines like `NotifyPropertyChanged("SpouseData.FirstName")` is wrong. There shoud be strictly a property name like "FirstName" and no dots or hierarchies like you did.

Comment: Make sure you really understand how `INotifyPropertyChanged` works.

Comment: @KostyaK Well INotifyPropertyChanged works everywhere else but here. I think it's not rebuilding the binding after the object is added.

Comment: It's simple. When you update SpouseData property you call NotifyPropertyChanged("SpouseData") in the object containing it. When you change `FirstName` you call NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName") but this time in SpouseData object.

Comment: @KostyaK So simple: `NotifyPropertyChanged("SpouseData")` How did I miss it? It's working great now. Thanks. I love Ukraine. Good memories!

Comment: You're welcome. :)